# Hiding some series in Google visualisation combo charts

Tags: google-visualization

I have a combo chart where I display a candle stick chart. I have defined series option as:

```
[{type: "candlesticks", targetAxisIndex:1}]
```

It works perfectly. Now, when a user clicks a button I want to display the same data in a line chart, instead of candlesticks. I want that the line is going through exit points of candles. What I am doing right now is that I change my series to:

```
[{type: "line", lineWidth:0, targetAxisIndex:1}, {type: "line", lineWidth:0, targetAxisIndex:1}, {type: "line", color:"blue", lineWidth:1, targetAxisIndex:1}, {type: "line", lineWidth:0, targetAxisIndex:1}]
```

I.e. I change the chart to 4 line charts with 3 of them having line with width equal to zero. It works well, however I feel it is not a good solution, because the library is probably recalculating and rendering all 4 lines. Is there a better solution to ignore a data serie from a combo chart?

Comment: You can use a dataView to set the displayed columns

Comment: No problem, good luck with proyect